# Ps Script to open a webpage in microsoft edge in Device Emulation mode?

Tags: bash, powershell, microsoft-edge

As I'm Trying to open a web page in Microsoft Edge in Device Emulation mode. Is there any bat Script or PowerShell Script to open the web page in Device emulation in Microsoft Edge ?

Or if I open a web page on the Microsoft Edge is there any possibility to get the current tab using PowerShell and we can navigate using manual method that supposed to implemented in PowerShell.

eg : if I press f12 dev toll is launched and need to select the Toggle Device Emulation. This need to be Scripted. Is there any possibilities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to open an Edge window, then use `SendKeys` to perform keystroke to open F12 dev tools and Toggle Device Emulation (Ctrl+Shift+M).

You can refer to the following sample code:

```
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("msedge","https://www.bing.com/")

Sleep 3 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Bing- Microsoft Edge') 
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{F12}') 
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('^+{M}')
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. Also I have a query is there any possibilities to enter the new URL in the current tab search box of the Bing home page.

Comment: Hi @Dood It's impossible to change the URL in this way. It only opens Edge and send some keys to it. If you want to interact with Edge more deeply, you need to [use WebDriver to automate Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp).

Comment: Yeah, by referring the above link for WebDrivers Automation I got an another idea and I have developed an script. Thanks @Yu Zhou.